# Reactor Mono publish to multiple methods

Tags: java, mono, project-reactor, spring-reactive

I have a problem in publishing an object to multiple methods. Simplified version of my code is given below.

```
package org.example.reactive;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.util.function.Tuple2;
import reactor.util.function.Tuple3;

@Slf4j
public class MonoTest {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        MonoTest m = new MonoTest();
        Mono<A> aMono = m.getA();
        Mono<B> bMono = aMono.flatMap(m::getB);
        Mono<C> cMono = aMono.flatMap(m::getC);
        Mono<D> dMono = cMono.zipWith(bMono).flatMap(m::getD);
        Mono<E> eMono = Mono.zip(aMono, cMono, dMono)
                .flatMap(m::getE);
        aMono
                .zipWith(eMono)
                .subscribe(m::onCompleted, m::onFailed);
    }

    private Mono<A> getA(){
        log.info("inside getA");
        return Mono.just(new A());
    }
    private Mono<B> getB(A a){
        log.info("inside getB");
        return Mono.just(new B());
    }
    private Mono<C> getC(A a){
        log.info("inside getC");
        return Mono.just(new C());
    }
    private Mono<D> getD(Tuple2 t){
        log.info("inside getD");
        return Mono.just(new D());
    }
    private Mono<E> getE(Tuple3 t){
        log.info("inside getE");
        return Mono.just(new E());
    }
    private void onCompleted(Tuple2 t){
        log.info("inside onCompleted");
    }
    private void onFailed(Throwable t){
        log.info("inside onFailed");
    }

    class A {}
    class B {}
    class C {}
    class D {}
    class E {}
}
```

I expect call to each method only once. But **getC** is invoked twice. What is wrong here? Program output is as follows

org.example.reactive.MonoTest - inside getA

org.example.reactive.MonoTest - inside getC

org.example.reactive.MonoTest - inside getC

org.example.reactive.MonoTest - inside getB

org.example.reactive.MonoTest - inside getD

org.example.reactive.MonoTest - inside getE

org.example.reactive.MonoTest - inside onCompleted

**EDIT**

Well, I could solve it by caching as follows.

```
        Mono<A> aMono = m.getA().cache();
        Mono<B> bMono = aMono.flatMap(m::getB).cache();
        Mono<C> cMono = aMono.flatMap(m::getC).cache();
        Mono<D> dMono = cMono.zipWith(bMono).flatMap(m::getD).cache();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two patterns in your set of `Mono`s:

- `aMono` is a constant and is resolved eagerly once, due to direct variable assingment (you call `getA()` once)
- on the other hand, other monos call `getX()` methods from within operators, notably `flatMap`. Which means these calls are performed lazily, when the flatmapping mono is subscribed to

`aMono` is the only top-level invocation of a `getX()` method.
Replace the `Mono` variables with their definition, except for `aMono` and it should become clearer what happens:

```
MonoTest m = new MonoTest();

Mono<A> aMono = m.getA(); // <-- getA log
aMono.zipWith(
    Mono.zip(
       aMono,
       aMono.flatMap(m::getC),  // <-- getC log
       aMono.flatMap(m::getC) // <-- getC log
            .zipWith(aMono.flatMap(m::getB)) // <-- getB log
            .flatMap(m::getD) // <-- getD log
    ).flatMap(m::getE) // <-- getE log
  ).subscribe(...);
```

which is why you get the number and order of logs you reported.

Comment: getC is invoked twice here as well.

Comment: I've rewritten equivalent code that better shows why getC is shown twice, as your question was asking the "why" , not the "how to fix"

Comment: note that you could append cache() to the declaration of cMono